# How to parse multiple lists into array of json objects, using Scala?

Tags: arrays, json, scala

How to convert multiple Lists (with equal number of elements) into Array of JSON Objects, using Scala?

Given:

```
List("Rec Type", "Evnt Type", "B/S Cd", "Sym"), 
List("cmn_rec_type", "cmn_event_type_cd", "cmn_buy_sell_cd", "cmn_issue_sym_id"),
List("Record Type", "Event Type", "Buy Sell Code", "Issue Symbol ID"),
List("Common", "Common", "Common", "Common", "Common")
```

Convert into:

```
[
{
"name":"Rec Type",
"id":"cmn_rec_type",
"description": "Record Type",
"recordType":"Common"
},
{
"name":"Evnt Type",
"id":"cmn_event_type_cd",
"description":"Event Type",
"recordType":"Common"
},
{
"name":"B/S Cd",
"id":"cmn_buy_sell_cd",
"description":"Buy Sell Code",
"recordType":"Common"
},
{
"name":"Sym",
"id":"cmn_issue_sym_id",
"description":"Issue Symbol ID",
"recordType":"Common"
}
]
```

Comment: Using which library? Also, why having a `List` if you know they will always have 4 elements?

Comment: Any Scala library. Same lists been used for verification of API response.

Comment: If you are implementing a JSON-based API (REST?), picking a suitable library to implement the API is much, much more important that working out how to do some minor JSON twiddling, if only because most libraries come with JSON support that can do this easily.

Comment: why 4th list has 5 element, while others have 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
listOrLists.transpose.map { case name :: id :: description :: recordType :: _ =>
  raw"""{ "name": "$name"
       |, "id": "$id"
       |, "description": "$description"
       |, "recordType": "$recordType"
       |}""".stripMargin
}.mkString("[", ",", "]")
```

Comment: How would use case would look like?

Comment: this code can be injected, because you don't escape characters. In 99% cases you should use library to create or parse JSON. Also you forgot about `.stripMargin`

Comment: @mbeider How should I know, it's your use case. I'm merely providing an answer for the requirements you've stated in your question.